# TeamCity Build Reports HTML pages not loading CSS/JS

Tags: report, teamcity, cucumber-java

I'm following this link to show cucumber HTML reports in a Build Report Tab.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results

In my BuildConfiguration I refer my artifacts as

```
api/target/cucumber-html-reports/cucumber-html-reports/** => report.zip
```

In project, report tab "Start Page" is like this

```
report.zip!/overview-steps.html
```

The tab is generated and I see the HTML page. BUT it doesn't load CSS/JS nor does it let me navigate to hyperlinks to other pages.

I get the following error when I click any link

> 403 Forbidden: Requests from build artifacts pages are restricted: Only requests to the same build's artifacts are allowed from the build artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that TeamCity auto generates "Build configuration ID" in CamelCase naming convention. When the Report Tab was trying to access the artifact using this camel case URL it didn't found anything.

I changed my project & build configurations IDs to all lower case and it worked smoothly. I hope this helps somebody.